# Sum of null and duplicate values across multiple columns in pyspark data framew

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`

```
data = [
("James","CA",None), (None,"AC",None),
("Ram","AC",200.0), ("Ram",None,None)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["name","state","number"])
df.show()

+-----+-----+------+
| name|state|number|
+-----+-----+------+
|James|   CA|  null|
| null|   AC|  null|
|  Ram|   AC| 200.0|
|  Ram| null|  null|
+-----+-----+------+
```

Below is what I am trying to achieve

I want to count the number of `nulls` in each column and then capture the count of nulls across all the columns as variable

I have done like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,isnan, when, count
df_null = df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])

df_null.show()
```

I get the below result

```
+-----+-----+------+
| name|state|number|
+-----+-----+------+
|    1|    1|     3|
+-----+-----+------+
```

What I want to do is capture `1+1+3` as a variable.

I have done like below

```
n_1 = df_null.collect()[0][0]
s_1 = df_null.collect()[0][1]   
nu_1 = df_null.collect()[0][2]

null_count = n_1 + s_1 + nu_1
```

Also I want to find duplicates of each column and then capture the count of duplicates across all the columns as variable

I have done like below

```
list_1 = ['name']

df_1 = df.groupby(list_1).count().where('count > 1')

+-----+-----+
| name|count|
+-----+-----+
|  Ram|    2|
+-----+-----+

list_2 = ['state']

df_2 = df.groupby(list_2).count().where('count > 1')

+------+-----+
| state|count|
+------+-----+
|    AC|    2|
+------+-----+

list_df1 = df_1.collect()[0][1]
list_df2 = df_2.collect()[0][1]

dup_count = list_df1 + list_df2
```

I am able to achieve what I want but trying to see if there is a better way to achieve

Comment: multiple collects of the same dataframe isn't very optimal, and looking at the example, you can absolutely just use collect once and extract required values using their indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing 3 collects of `df_null`, which can be reduced to a single `collect`. Multiple actions on the same dataframe will retrigger its lineage.

```py
nulls_per_col = data_sdf. \
    select(*[func.sum(func.col(k).isNull().cast('int')).alias(k) for k in data_sdf.columns]). \
    collect()

print(nulls_per_col)
# [Row(name=1, state=1, number=3)]

null_count = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [nulls_per_col[0][k] for k in data_sdf.columns])

print(null_count)
# 5
```